# Linq conversion

Tags: linq, iqueryable

I am using the following code to return an IList:

```
public IList<string> FindCodesByCountry(string country)
        {
            var query = from q in session.Linq<Store>()
                        where q.Country == country
                        orderby q.Code
                        select new {q.Code};

            return (IList<string>) query.ToList();
        }
```

However I keep getting this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]'.

What I am supposed to return here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as long as q.code is a string this should work:
note that it is not creating an anonymous object, just the string is being selected.

```
    public IList<string> FindCodesByCountry(string country)
    {
        var query = from q in session.Linq<Store>()
                    where q.Country == country
                    orderby q.Code
                    select q.Code;

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: ouch..... not sure how I missed that... I thought I **had** to use the **new** operator to return a single column.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you were selecting an anonymous type?  If not try this...

```
    var query = from q in session.Linq<Store>()
                where q.Country == country
                orderby q.Code
                select q.Code;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
query.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToList();
```

Or

```
query.Cast<String>().ToList();
```

But I'm assuming that `q.Code` is a string?  In which case you just want to change your LINQ expression:

```
var query = from q in session.Linq<Store>()
                    where q.Country == country
                    orderby q.Code
                    select q.Code;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query, instead of selecting an anonymous class containing a string, just select the string itself:

```
var query = from q in session.Linq<Store>()
            where q.Country == country
            orderby q.Code
            select q.Code;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a list of custom types to a list of strings like that.  The easiest way would be to have your `query` object begin it's life as an iEnumerable list of strings, rather than a custom type.  Change your select line to:

`select new q.Code.toString();`

and you'll be good.  If q.Code is itself a string to begin with, then the `.ToString()` won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return query.ToList<string>();
```